# c# multi structured classes

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have a question regarding classes.  At the moment I use simple classes for example:

```
public class Core
{
   public double Parameter1;
   public double Parameter2;

   public double Calc1()
   {
      return(Parameter1 * Paramater2);
   }
}
```

In my main code I then create an object of the class, and use it as follows:

```
Core core = new Core();
core.Parameter1 = 2;
core.Parameter2 = 3;
double x = core.Calc1();
```

Now my question is, how do I structure classes to have for example the following functionalities:

```
core.Calculations.Calc1();
core.Calculations.Calc2();
```

At the moment I can only have core.Calc1() etc not core.Calculations.Calc1();

I use code such as the following many times from existing libraries, and I need to do the same:

```
zedDistVectorAAR.AccessibilityObject.Bounds.Bottom.CompareTo();
```

I have no idea how to structure such classes.

I have tried all types of classes from nested to everything in the book but I cannot get a structure such as the above one.  Since it is used everywhere I'm missing something.  I have really looked through many articles and books but my lack of formal IT education and lack of the correct terminologies are really getting me down.

For example what I want to do is I want to have a class, that can give me different price quotes:

```
double open = data.Financial.Open;
double close = data.Financial.Close;
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What is Calculations I don't see this field in yor class?

Comment: @Serghei - He is asking how to implement such a calling convention.

Comment: And another question what you need to different methods Calc1() and Calc2() what should they return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need to have that class instanced?
for example with

```
class something
{
    public class somethingnested
    {
        public class somethingtotalynested
        {
            public static string str;
        }
    }
}
```

you could get

```
something.somethingnested.somethingtotalynested.str = "";
```

otherwise you could do something like this

```
class something
    {
        public somethingnested sn;

        public class somethingnested
        {
            public somethingtotalynested stn;
            public class somethingtotalynested
            {
                public string str;
            }

            public somethingnested()
            {
                this.stn = new somethingtotalynested();
            }
        }

        public something()
        {
            this.sn = new somethingnested();
        }
    }
```

and acces str with

```
    sss.sn.stn.str = "";
```

Comment: All the other answers can be used but yours is going to be the easiest to implement in my opinion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could for example simply add a property of type `Calculations` in your `Core` class:

```
public class Core
{
    public Core(int param1, int param2)
    {
        this.Calculations = new Calculations { Parameter1 = param1, Parameter2 = param2 };
    }

    public Calculations Calculations { get; private set; }
}

public class Calculations
{
    public double Parameter1 { get; set; }

    public double Parameter2 { get; set; }

    public double Calc1()
    {
        return this.Parameter1 * this.Parameter2;
    }
}
```

Then it's possible to call it using:

```
Core dd = new Core(10, 20);
double res = dd.Calculations.Calc1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add a collection of type Core to your Core class.

```
public class Core
{
    public double Parameter1;
    public double Parameter2;

    public Core()
    {
        this.Calculations = new List<Core>();
    }

    public double Calc1()
    {
        return (Parameter1 * Parameter2);
    }

    public List<Core> Calculations { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better concept building,  try explore concepts of Association, Composition and Aggregation in c#. Studying these will give you some idea about how relationships between classes exist. Also, try exploring Design Patterns which will enable you to come up with better solutions:

[Composite Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx)